# CLI python, not displaying in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run an example from `https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/` and I'm having some trouble. I've set up a `setup.py` with the following...

```
setup(
    name='test',
    version='0.1.0',
    py_modules=['testpy'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'test = testpy.py:cli',
        ],
    },
)
```

and this is what's in my testpy.py

```
import click
# import setup ## thought this would import the python file setup.py, doesn't seem like it does
@click.command()
@click.argument('name')
def cli(name):
    click.echo(f"Hello world{name}")
```

I'm using VS Code, I've also tried running this in the windows command line as well as a Linux terminal `Debian`

Whenever I try to run this example, nothing gets displayed in the terminal, it seems like it's executed. For example,

```
C:\Users\Luis\VSCODE\test_python> python testpy.py luis 
C:\Users\Luis\VSCODE\test_python>
```

Nothing get's displayed...

I've tried running the other example documented in Click, which works just fine for me. I don't know why I'm having trouble with this example. I've made sure I've followed the instructions, maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your `setup.py` file do you have `from distutils.core import setup` at the top?

Comment: @Brian I dont, I'll have to try that. Thanks for pointing that out.